# equivalent of file:// or txmt:// protocol for Eclipse PDT 2.1?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, xdebug, eclipse-pdt

I am using xdebug with eclipse (on OSX).  I think I remember reading somewhere that it was possible to link the error output (or the Call Stack) to a text editor (like Textmate).  I was wondering if its possible to do the same thing for Eclipse.

**EDIT:** I found out that what I would like to use is the xdebug.file_link_format setting.  For OSX and to open in TextMate, the setting would be: 
    xdebug.file_link_format = "txmt://open?url=file://%f&line=%l"

Any idea how to do this with Eclipse PDT 2.1?  I know I could use the file:// protocol, but a) i don't want to set the system wide default for PHP to eclipse and b) this wouldn't link it to the project, just the raw file.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do it with NetBeans. You need to add this line to your php.ini file:

`xdebug.remote_enable=On`

Comment: i have xdebug working already (with remote_enable=On) but I want the nice error reporting that xdebug spits out to my browser to have links to my editor in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to register custome protocol and define links using that protocol

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Register_protocol

It works for me . My xdebug links are sth like eclipse://[pathtofile]

:)

check this also

http://www.jaylib.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/EclipsePlugins/EclipseCall